# Pass color between pages - colorPicker control

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, xaml, windows-phone-7

I use ColorPicker control from c4f toolkit and I want to send color between pages. 
I pass like this:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/GeneratePage.xaml?foreground=" + CodeColorPicker.Color, UriKind.Relative));
```

and in GeneratePage.xaml I retrieve data like this:

```
var colorCode = NavigationContext.QueryString["foreground"].ToString();
```

But content is empty. I tried assign to textblock

```
test.Text = colorCode;
```

Unfortunately textblock is empty.

I also tried to write a converter from a string to ARGB, but if the string is empty it will not do anything. Does anyone have an idea how to send?

Comment: If you use `CodeColorPicker.Color.ToString()` does `colorCode` contains any value?

Comment: can you provide a sample of the source code over at [http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create) so I can attach a debugger against it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your color code starts with a '#'. Therefore, your URL looks like:

```
/GeneratePage.xaml?foreground=#000000
```

The part after the '#' is interpreted as an anchor, and your foreground parameter is therefore empty.

To fix that, you can either encode your URL or just strip the '#' from your color code:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/GeneratePage.xaml?foreground=" + CodeColorPicker.Color.ToString().TrimStart('#'), UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: I agree with KooKiz, I did a test from the sample from the c4f toolkit and doing This should throw an exception actually.  I did a quick test and I got a UriFormatException due to exactly what KooKiz stated.

Doing:
`new System.Uri("/MainPage.xaml?color=" + pickerVisibilityToggle.Color)`

will throw that exception.  With a break point set, I can see the color as well.